# How to delete repeating letters in a string?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a function which will return me the string of unique characters present in the passed string. Here's my code:

```
def repeating_letters(given_string):
    counts = {}
    for char in given_string:
        if char in counts:
            return char
        else: 
            counts[char] = 1
            if counts[char] > 1:
                del(char)
            else:
                return char
```

I am not getting expected results with it. How can I get the desired result.

Here when I am passing this string as input:

```
sample_input = "abcadb"
```

I am expecting the result to be:

```
"abcd"
```

However my code is returning me just:

```
 nothing
```

Comment: Please provide all the elements of a [MCVE], including sample inputs, expected outputs, and actual output (the "wrong" output).

Comment: @Swarali How are you running the code?

Comment: Your example currently has a syntax error at the `for` loop.

Comment: `return` exits the entire loop, stopping iteration; `del(char)` will delete the *variable* `char`, not the string element, and even if it did delete the string element, it would be UB since you're iterating and deleting at the same time; you also only ever set the array values to `1`, never greater than `1`. Perhaps you should start off on a more approachable task.

Comment: @SwaraliKargaonkar well it's returning "a" for me *(unlike nothing as you mentioned in the question)*

Answer (score 2):

```
def repeating_letters(given_string):
    seen = set()
    ret = []
    for c in given_string:
        if c not in seen:
            ret.append(c)
            seen.add(c)
    return ''.join(ret)
```

Here we add each letter to the set `seen` the first time we see it, at the same time adding  it to a list `ret`.  Then we return the `join`ed list.

Comment: (Disclaimer: this is my gut feeling,. I haven't tested it).  I thought that the `O(1)` member tests would beat the `O(n)` membership tests of strings, even considering the costs of adding elements to the set.  (Especially for string that are mostly repeated characters)

Comment: ah so it was the performance improvement, thought that was the likely case

Comment: @NickA [Here's a test](https://repl.it/@Haugh/HardtofindEvenGalapagossealion) It looks like the `set` way is indeed faster.  (Of course it will also take more memory)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the *one-liner* to achieve this if the **order in the resultant string matters** via using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) with [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) as:

```
>>> my_str = 'abcadbgeg'

>>> ''.join(sorted(set(my_str),key=my_str.index))
'abcdge'
```

Here sorted will sort the characters in the `set` based on the first index of each in the original string, resulting in ordered list of characters.

However if the **order in the resultant string doesn't matter**, then you may simply do:

```
>>> ''.join(set(my_str))
'acbedg'
```

Comment: what does ' ' do?

Comment: @SwaraliKorgaonkar it joins all the string in the list with empty string `''`